# How to store and retrieve auth_token to/from AccountManager

Tags: android, authentication, accountmanager

I am using `AccountManager` for storing auth_token. I am using the following code to store the auth_token. But I am not able to retrieve it back.

```
AccountManager.get(this).addAccountExplicitly(account, "", bundle);
```

And, I am using following code (using Volley library) to retrieve it back, but it's throwing AuthFailureError.

```
try {
    Logging.d(LOG_TAG, "AUTH TOKEN : "
            + (new AndroidAuthenticator(this, account,
                    CustomAuthenticator.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE).getAuthToken()));
} catch (AuthFailureError e) {
    Logging.d(LOG_TAG, "AUTH FAILURE");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could able to retrieve the auth_token through this snippet:

```
final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = AccountManager.get(this)
        .getAuthToken(account, authTokenType, null, this, null, null);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Bundle bnd = future.getResult();
            final String authtoken = bnd
                    .getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
            Logging.d(LOG_TAG, (authtoken != null) ? "SUCCESS!\ntoken: "
                    + authtoken : "FAIL");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();                }
    }
}).start();
```